# Icons with .js extension

Tags: finder

I ran *CleanMyMac 3* earlier today and after **cleaning** my MacBook all my .js files have PHPStorm icon. How can I reset it to default icon ?

[image: See Photo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-associate the default application.

1. Select a `.js` file and Get Info, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>
2. Expand **Open With** and choose an application from the pop-up that you want to open .js files with.
3. Click **Change all**

You may need to log out and back in again for all the icon to refresh

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. I restarted Mac a it's still showing those ugly icons :(

Comment: After re-associating, what happens when you open one of the effected `.js` files? If it still opens in phpstorm, you may have other issues. Try restarting in Safe mode, and if that fails, run the following in terminal: `update_dyld_shared_cache -force`. If it does open in the new program, you might need to un-install PHPstorm, set the binding, then re-install.

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty easy, here's how you do it:

1. First of all select your folder/file in Finder, then right click on it and select Get Info.
2. In the info panel, click on folder/file preview in the top left corner.
3. Now, when the preview is highlighted, hit backspace ( ← ) on your keyboard.
4. Done!

*If you cant select that .js than do the same thing to a different .js*

Comment: All of my .js, .css, .php files are using this icon, which means it'd be a lot of work to do that manually.